# Posting to Facebook without a link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, cfhttp, facebook-rest-api

I'm working on an API to allow posting to Facebook, using Graph API over REST, sending HTTP post requests to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed` (after succesful OAuth2 auth).

I can specify `message` and `link` and it posts the link, (but with message ignored?), and I can also include `name`, `caption` and `description` to get those elements handled - so links are ok.

If I use just `message` or just `picture`, I get the error:

> (#100) Missing message or attachment

If I use `message` *and* `picture`, it posts the message, without any picture. (Which is useful, but not intended behaviour?)

The only way I can get the picture seems to be as a link (which includes it as a thumbnail).

I've looked through the docs but can't find any useful info on this - all the examples are showing links.

My main question is: **What is the intended way to post a message without a picture or link?**

But it'd also be useful to know if there's a way to post a picture to the wall? (non-thumbnail, with lightbox)

Comment: It depends on how you are actually doing that, a proper URL is like 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?method=POST&message=3%20Auch%20am%202012%2F09%2F28%20publizieren!&published=false&scheduled_publish_time=1348783200&format=json&access_token=AAAC....' and if your doing POST everything needs to be URL-Form encoded etc.

Comment: The URL was `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<snip>&format=json` - with the data supposedly being specified as additional URL params. When I manually placed the message in the query string - i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=test+message&access_token=<snip>&format=json` - it now appears to be working, so might be a bug with CF's cfhttpparam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual code is more complex, but simplified here to demonstrate the issue.

This was failing:

```
<cfhttp
    result = "local.Response"
    method = "post"
    url    = #Arguments.Url#
    >
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Message" value="#Arguments.Message#" />
</cfhttp>
```

This worked:

```
<cfset Arguments.Url &= '&message=' & encodeForUrl(Arguments.Message) />

<cfhttp
    result = "local.Response"
    method = "post"
    url    = #Arguments.Url#
    >
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="dummy" value="ignore" />
</cfhttp>
```

*(The dummy cfhttpparam is because CF complains if a POST request doesn't contain at least one param.)*